# Why the Size of int specifically is 4 byte in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, int, clr

The size of int is 2 byte in c and 4 in c#.why is that ?. Why not 2 byte like c. i searched on the web also but i've not found anything. I am searching for the real technical reason of this.

Answer (score 5):

In C#, int means Int32 i.e., int is an alias for Int32. Hence int is always 32 bit which is equivalent to 4 bytes. And it was made so as to make it compatible with 32 bit and 64 bit platform. If you write Int64 then it is 8 bytes.

You can refer this MSDN: [What is the size of int in c#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7ebf4a88-2bf5-448d-8abe-c63ad7938429/what-is-the-size-of-int-in-c?forum=csharplanguage)

Answer (score 4):

That’s incorrect.  The size of `int` in C can be two, four or eight bytes depending on whether you compile the program as 16-bit, 32-bit, or ILP64, but today it’s almost always 32 bits.

The 32-bit integer type usually has the shortest and simplest name because most computers today run most efficiently when they’re working with 32 bits of data.  64-bit machines can run 32-bit code much faster than 32-bit machines can work with 64-bit numbers.  While `int` could be, and sometimes is, defined as 64 bits on a 64-bit machine, this can introduce a lot of subtle bugs when compiling code that was written and tested on a 32-bit machine.

If you want to work with an exact number of bits, there are types in both languages that let you specify an exact width.